# Is the provided solution complete? Or is there any aspect left to prove?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The question given is :

> Let $\displaystyle x\ =\ ( x_{1} ,\ x_{2} ,\ ...,\ x_{n}) ,\ y\ =\ ( y_{1} ,\ y_{2} ,\ ...,\ y_{n}) ,$ where $\displaystyle x_{i} ,\ y_{i} \ \in \ \mathbb{R}$. We write $\displaystyle x\  >\ y$ if for some $\displaystyle k$, $\displaystyle 1\ \leqslant \ k\ \leqslant \ n\ -\ 1$, $\displaystyle x_{1} \ =\ y_{1} ,\ ...,\ x_{k} \ =\ y_{k}$ but $\displaystyle x_{k\ +\ 1} \  >\ y_{k\ +\ 1}$. If we have $\displaystyle u\ =\ ( u_{1} ,\ u_{2} ,\ ...,\ u_{n}) ,\ v\ =\ ( v_{1} ,\ v_{2} ,\ ...,\ v_{n}) ,\ w\ =\ ( w_{1} ,\ w_{2} ,\ ...,\ w_{n}) ,\ z\ =\ ( z_{1} ,\ z_{2} ,\ ...,\ z_{n})$ such that $\displaystyle u\  >\ v,\ w\  >\ z$. Prove $\displaystyle u\ +\ w\  >\ v\ +\ z$.

The following is my proof for it :

Let the $\displaystyle k$ for $\displaystyle u-v$ relation be $\displaystyle a$ and for $\displaystyle w-z\ $relation be $\displaystyle b$

**Case 1 : $\displaystyle a\ =\ b$**

Then we have
$\displaystyle u_{a\ +\ 1} \  >\ v_{a\ +\ 1}$ and $\displaystyle w_{a\ +\ 1} \  >\ z_{a\ +\ 1}$ and it is trivial that $\displaystyle u_{a\ +\ 1} \ +\ w_{a\ +\ 1} \ \  >\ z_{a\ +\ 1} +\ v_{a\ +\ 1}$

**Case 2 : $\displaystyle a\  >\ b$**

The inequality is achieved earlier by $\displaystyle w-z$
$\displaystyle u_{b\ +\ 1} \ =\ v_{b\ +\ 1}$ as $\displaystyle b< \ a$ and as per definition.

So adding this to the $\displaystyle w-z$ inequality is equivalent to adding a real constant to both sides of an inequality.

Hence, $\displaystyle u_{b+\ 1} \ +\ w_{b\ +\ 1} \ \  >\ z_{b\ +\ 1} +\ v_{b\ +\ 1}$ will hold true.

Reversing case 2 will yield the similar result for $\displaystyle a\ < \ b$
Hence, proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems correct to me, but your phrasing in Case 2 is a little unclear.
You could probably just use sum of inequalities to prove this.
$$v < u \Rightarrow v + z < u + z$$
$$z < w \Rightarrow z + u < w + u$$
$$\Rightarrow v + z < u + w$$